# How to make average reviews rating show in index page per object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I Have a Ruby on Rails app that is supposed to help review Hospitals.
I followed a close tutorial to build thus far and have a fairly workable application.

I am trying to add some more new feautures to the app

1. I would like users to see a list of Hospitals in the database from the home page clearly showing hospital name, image and average reviews

I can successfully display the hospitals, images and phone numbers on the index/home pag but struggling to show an average rating of all reviews per hospital.
It is weird because i have the exact same structure on the individual hospital show pages and it works fine there.

I feel like i am just a few steps away and need assistance. Please see code snippets below:

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="jumboFluid">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <section class="content">
      <%= form_tag search_hospitals_path, method: :get, class: "form-group" do %>
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-addon">Search</div>
            <p>
              <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  class: "form-control formInput", placeholder: "Eye, Maternity" %>
              <%# <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div> 
      <% end %>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hospitalList">
  <h1 id="hospitalBanner">Hospitals</h1>
  <blockquote> 
    <p class="text-center"><cite>&#8220;Explore the best of healthcare available in your community&#8221;</cite> </p>
  </blockquote>

  <% content_for(:body_attributes) do %>
    data-no-turbolink="false"
  <% end %>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <% @hospitals.each do |hospital| %>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <%= link_to image_tag(hospital.image), hospital %>
            <div class="caption">
              <p> <%= link_to hospital.name, hospital %></p>
              <p> <%= hospital.phone %></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <br>

    <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to 'New Hospital', new_hospital_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
    <% end %>

<script>
  $('.star-rating').raty({
    path: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/morafamedapp/stars',
    readOnly: true,
    score: function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
</script>

</div>
```

Working show code

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= image_tag @hospital.image_url unless @hospital.image.blank? %>

    <h3>
      <%= @hospital.name %>
    </h3>

    <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= @avg_rating %> ></div>
    <p><%= "#{@reviews.length} reviews" %></p>
    <%= social_share_button_tag("Share") %>


    <p>
      <strong>Address:</strong>
      <%= @hospital.address %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Phone:</strong>
      <%= @hospital.phone %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Website:</strong>
      <%= link_to @hospital.website, @hospital.website, target: :_blank %>
    </p>

    <%= link_to "Write a Review", new_hospital_review_path(@hospital), class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <br>
    <br>

    <iframe width="230" height="230" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=<%= @hospital.address.parameterize %>&key=AIzaSyAc4mTzAGIA_8JFXAcL3XTBi-tzuxQCsBc" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-9">
    <% if @reviews.blank? %>
      <h3>No reviews yet. Be the first to write one!</h3>
    <% else %>
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-md-3"></th>
            <th class="col-md-9"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <% @reviews.each do |review| %>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <h4>
                  <%= "#{review.user.first_name.capitalize} #{review.user.last_name.capitalize[0]}." %>
                </h4>
                <p><%= review.created_at.strftime("%-d/%-m/%y") %></p>
              </td>

              <td>
                <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= review.rating %> ></div>
                <p><%= h(review.comment).gsub(/\n/, '<br/>').html_safe %></p>
                <%= social_share_button_tag("Share") %>

                <% if user_signed_in? %>
                  <% if (review.user == current_user) || (current_user.admin?) %>
                  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_hospital_review_path(@hospital, review) %>
                  <%= link_to "Delete", hospital_review_path(@hospital, review), method: :delete %>

                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_hospital_path(@hospital), class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', hospitals_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>

<script>
  $('.star-rating').raty({
    path: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/morafamedapp/stars',
    readOnly: true,
    score: function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
</script>
```

**hospital.rb**

```
class Hospital < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  searchkick

  has_many :reviews

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Hospital.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end 

  def self.avg_rating
    Hospital.avg_rating
  end


end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
    <h3>
      <%= @hospital.name %>
    </h3>

    <%= @hospital.avg_rating %>

    <p><%= "#{@reviews.length} reviews" %></p>
```

**Error**

```
Showing /Users/oluwaseunmorafa/medaapp1/app/views/hospitals/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:
undefined method `avg_rating' for #<Hospital:0x007fd846496ee0>
Extracted source (around line #9):
7
8
9
10
11
12

    </h3>

    <%= @hospital.avg_rating %>

    <p><%= "#{@reviews.length} reviews" %></p>
```

Comment: It seems like you've included large amounts of unnecessary code, and omitted a lot of code that is actually relevant. Your question should contain an [MCVE] with the *minimal* amount of code necessary to reproduce your problem. You're asking about a problem with your `index` view, but you haven't included that view in your question. There's also no reason to include the entire Reviews controller. Please edit your question to remove the unrelated code and include whatever code you've written for your index view, even if it's currently not working, along with whatever error it's generating.

Comment: The quick answer: Group reviews by `hospital_id`, then for each collection calculate their `average`. The not-so-quick answer: This does not scale very well. If you plan to grow this application to show average reviews for *lots* of hospitals, then you should *cache the result* somewhere rather than re-calculate it every time you load the page. But if this only intended as a quick little experimental project, then don't worry about that.

Comment: Hi @oluwaseun-morafa, it is awesome you gave us this much information. However it makes your question hard to read. It would be better to focus on the problem area, and make that clearer. If I read it correctly, you have a problem when showing a single hospital, and then showing? calculating? the average review? Ha wait, after your edit I understand the problem: you want to show the average in the index view like you do on the show page? (where it works?)

Comment: @nathanvda Precisely.

Comment: In your show-view you calculate `avg_rating`, but you would have to do that for each line in the index. I would move the calculation of the `avg_rating` to the `Hospital` class, and then you can just write `hospital.avg_rating` and it will work in the index and the show page.

Comment: Looping through `hospital.avg_rating` will work, but now (without cacheing) you're hitting a classic N+1 query problem. But again, if this is just a little fun project then don't worry about that for now....

Comment: Hey Oluwaseun Morafa I agree with nathanvda avg_rating seems like a good instace method for the Hospital class

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, i still cannot get it to work for some reason. I moved the avg_rating to the Hospital class as @nathanvda suggested but i get the error "undefined method". Please bear with me as i am newbie.

Comment: @Tom Lord1 It is currently a pet project but i would love for it to grow into something much more. I am interested in your views on how best to implement this with scaling in mind.

Comment: I would gladly show how you could do this. Please add your implementation of the method in your question. @meagar what do we need to do to reopen this question?

Comment: @nathanvda I have added as requested, even i know there is a lot wrong but i'm only just learning, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Hospital` class you define a class method instead of an instance method. So remove the `self.avg_rating` method and instead write:

```
  def avg_rating
    review.average(:rating)
  end
```

And then in your views (in show and index) you can just refer to `hospital.avg_rating` to show the rating.